# How to COUNT in a specific column after GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ruby

I'm stuck with how to write SQL statements, so I would appreciate it if you could teach me.

## Current status

- items table

| id | session_id | item_id | competition_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 7 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 | 2 |

## want to

grouping by competition_id,
Count the same numbers in item_id,Extract the most common numbers and their numbers.

For example

If competition_id is 1,item_id → 2 ,and the number is 3
If competition_id is 2,item_id → 5 ,and the number is 2
If competition_id is 3,・・・
If competition_id is 4,・・・

## environment

macOS BigSur
ruby 2.7.0
Rails 6.1.1
sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In statistics, what you are asking for is the *mode*, the most common value.

You can use aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select ct.*
from (select competition_id, item_id, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by competition_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by competition_id, item_id
     ) ci
where seqnum = 1;
```

In the event that there are ties, this returns only one of the values, arbitrarily.  If you want all modes when there are ties use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.